# Unexpected error when trying to find the max deviation between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
baseline = numpy.load("path_to_my_file",allow_pickle=True)
follow_up = numpy.load("path_to_my_other_file",allow_pickle=True)
diff = np.subtract(follow_up,baseline)
norm = np.amax(diff)
```

This gives me a bizarre error of `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` for the last line.

Just....what?  What truth value?  What I EXPECT numpy to do, is flatten `diff` and give me the max, how does that translate to a truth value?

If it matters, both `baseline` and `follow_up` have a shape of (16,288), but that REALLY shouldn't matter?

Comment: What does `diff` look like? Part of the values, what shape, what dtype?

Comment: Same shape as `baseline` and `follow_up`, but dtype is showing up as `object` when that is not what I expect.  I think this is on to something...

Comment: Check the dtype of `baseline` and `follow_up`. There's likely a problem reading one of those datasets (or rather, with one of your datasets).